# Subtract a value from previous row respecting the grouping

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `movm` (
    `id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `product` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `value` DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
    -- ...
);
```

And a couple of data:

```
INSERT INTO `movm`(`product`, `value`) VALUES 
    (1, 1000),
    (1, -200),
    (1,  100),
    (2,   50),
    (2,  -10),
    (1,  100),
    (2,  -20);
```

And I'd expect to get the following result:

```
+----+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| id | product | value   | previous | current |
+----+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|  1 |       1 | 1000.00 |        0 |    1000 |
|  2 |       1 | -200.00 |     1000 |     800 |
|  3 |       1 |  100.00 |      800 |     900 |
|  6 |       1 |  100.00 |      900 |    1000 |
|  4 |       2 |   50.00 |        0 |      50 |
|  5 |       2 |  -10.00 |       50 |      40 |
|  7 |       2 |  -20.00 |       40 |      20 |
```

But always respecting a `GROUP BY` *product*.

I've tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `product`,
    `value`,
    @previous := (@current)           AS `previous`,
    @current  := (@current + `value`) AS `current`
    FROM
        `movm`,
        (
            SELECT
                @previous := 0,
                @current  := 0
        ) AS `__movm`;
```

Because it doesn't respect the group by, it always sums everything, and there's no tiebreaker.

Already did `IF(@product != product, @current := 0, NULL)`; works, but not so much flexible. And I also need to track only the values for that product, bypassing any order, as you see, they're not sorted (I'd think that this is easy to solve wrapping current the SQL in a sub-query).

So: is there a better solution which I can use `GROUP BY product` and get the expected result as shown?

Comment: How is the approach using `@product != product..` not flexible?  I think that's the best option for MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have another variable to keep track of the product and also you need `order by` so that you can change the `product` variable and reset `counters` when product value changes.

This will work.

```
SELECT
    id,
    product,
    value,
    @previous := IF( @prevProduct = product,@current,0)           AS previous,
    @current  := IF( @prevProduct = product, @current + value, value) AS current,
    @prevProduct := product as var_val 
    FROM
    movm,
        (
            SELECT
                @previous := 0,
                @current  := 0,
                @prevProduct := NULL
        ) AS `__movm`
    ORDER BY product
```